# Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'setImage'

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
@IBAction func houseLock(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.houseLock.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_lock_open_3x"),forState: UIControlState.normal)
    self.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_lock_outline_3x"), forState: UIControlState.selected)
}
```

All I want to do is change the button image on click. So when it is clicked, it will be a lock button and if it’s clicked again, it will be unlocked. I found a couple of things on stack that had similar problems but the answers weren't really explained thoroughly. I am new to this so was wondering if some can explain the error I'm getting.

> Value of type '`(UIButton) -> ()`' has no member '`setImage`'

EDIT****

```
IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.button.setImage(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "ic_lock_outline_3x"), for: .normal)
    self.button.setImage(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "ic_lock_open_3x"), for: .selected)

}
```

Comment: this is swift not objectiveC

Comment: Your code seems to be randomly copied&pasted. `super.viewDidLoad()` belongs to `viewDidLoad()`, `self` is the enclosing class where the method is located and `houseLock` is used as property and as method name. That's pretty confusing.

Comment: yeah you're right I forgot to take that out from some stuff I was trying... My bad

Comment: By the way `sender` is the reference to the button which triggered the action.

Comment: why am I getting so many down votes lol wanna know for the future..

Comment: @Matherz check the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to ask a good question and prevent getting downvotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@IBAction` function has the same name as the button, this causes a name ambiguity. Change the name of the function to something else.

```
@IBAction func houseLockPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
```

Also, you are missing the button's name in the third line. Change `self` to `self.houseLock` to refer to the button.

Comment: But, OP uses `self.`, clearly referencing the button.

Comment: @Xcoder `self.` also references the function, since it belongs to the class as well.

Comment: for me works just fine, using the name of the fuction equal to the button name

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit confused. Where do I find the buttons name? I tried changing the functions name and I still have the same problem

Comment: @Matherz do you have an outlet for your button?

Comment: @Xcoder So I made it in the storyboard. I just dragged the button on the view and dragged that button in the class.

Comment: About your `setImage()` method: does it exist in the class or is it an extension of UIButton?

Comment: Well I thought it was an extension of the button. I did not make a function called setImage

Comment: while using the latest Xcode 10 beta, I have faced this name ambiguity for custom UIButton which worked fine in previous Xcode versions. @the4kman thanks.